# Using binary search and recursion to search a text file

Tags: python, file, sorting, search

I want to use recursion and binary search to search a text file for a username and password. Each account (username and password) are saved on one line, with a space separating the two.

This is what I currently have (does work), just want to use more techniques:

```
def validation(username1, password1):
    file = open("Accounts.txt", "r")
    for line in file:
        line = line.split("\n")
        line = line[0].split(" ")

        if username1 == line[0] and password1 == line[1]:
            main_menu()     #main_menu() will allow the user to enter the game
        else:
            valid = Label(root, text="Account not found try again or sign up")
            valid.place(x=215, y=130)
            login()        #will recall the login window and ask them to renter details 
    file.close()
```

I have the following code which I want to use:

```
def validation(username1, password1):
    file = open("Accounts.txt", "r")
```

userame1 and passwrod1 are the details that the user have entered. I now want to check that an account has already been created using binary search and recursion.

Amy ideas on how to do this? I'm still learning how to code.

Comment: Your requirement still isn't clear, you've mentioned binary, recursion and bubble sort?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur sorry about that I have changed the question x

Comment: Read all lines, sort that list, and then use binary search? What's the issue here

Comment: @AbhinavMathur could you please give me an example

Comment: @Katie010203 Neither binary search nor recursion seem particularly relevant to this task. If you want to use an alternative approach, I would suggest creating a dict with usernames as keys and passwords as values. Then if the username wasn't in the resulting dict, your program would prompt to create a new account; but if it was, the program would check the password, and if it was wrong, prompt the user (using a while-loop) to enter the correct one.

Comment: @ekhumoro would it be possible to use either thou? thanks x

Comment: Unless you've explicitly been told to use this approach, @ekhumoro's approach is the most practical

Comment: @Katie010203 I suppose you could use binary search to find the username, but it isn't really suited to your particular task. Binary search is most useful when you need to quickly find a value in a very long, pre-sorted list. It's extremely efficient at doing this, which is why it is often used by databases. Recursion is most useful when searching or traversing hierachical data structures.

Comment: @ekhumoro okay thanks x

Comment: @Katie010203 Binary search would make more sense for a password-strength checker. You could have a big dictionary of common words and then do a binary search of it to see if the password is in it. If so, your checker would reject the password and ask the user for a stronger one.

Comment: @ekhumoro that's a good idea thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to read all lines and sort them, so that binary search can be applied.

```py
def validation(username1, password1):
    file = open("Accounts.txt", "r")
    lines = [i.strip().split() for i in file.readlines()]
    # lines is a list of [username, password] sublists
    lines.sort()
    if binary_search(lines, [username1, password1]):
        login()
    else:
        print(“User Not Found”)
```

Comment: is "binary_search" some sort of function? x

Comment: @Katie010203 See the [bisect module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#module-bisect) in the python stdlib.

Answer (score -2):

you can try to see if a specific word is in the text file:

```
def validation(username1, password1):
    file = open("Accounts.txt", "r")
    content = file.read()

    if str(username1) and str(password1) in content:
        return True

    else:
        return False
```

And then call main_menu() or login() depending of the result of validation()

Comment: does this use recursion and binary search? x

Comment: I'm not gonna lie, i have absolutely no idea. But i would say yes

Comment: @persephone no, it doesn't. Please read up on the terminologies first